# How to get consistency in received wifi signal strength?

Tags: android, networking, android-wifi, wifimanager, kalman-filter

I am using wifi signals in my android application. The problem is, when I receive the strength of signals in a numerical value, the value keeps fluctuating a alot. The problems arise when there is a wall between me and access point or router or when there are a lot of people in that place. Is there any way to cope with this problem? Any filters or mechanisms?

Comment: What does this question have to do with programming?

Comment: what are you actually trying to do? what do you want to do with the strength you receive? show it on the screen?

Comment: It fluctuates a lot by nature. A lot of things affect the signal strength. You could keep an average/median strength in the past 5 seconds or something like that.